# Additions based on item frequency in an array (Lua)

Tags: arrays, lua

I have an array which is used to compute a score in a game:

```
a = {1,7,5,1,2,6,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7}
```

All numbers should be simply added, except when a number appears several times, for instance 7 (which appears 4 times) it should be added as such:

```
1*7 + 2*7 + 3*7 + 4*7
```

So, altogether, array "a" should give this score:

```
score = (1*1 + 2*1) + (1*2 + 2*2) + (1*3) + (1*4) + (1*5 + 2*5 + 3*5) + (1*6 + 2*6) + (1*7 + 2*7 + 3*7 + 4*7)
```

I wouldn't know where to start doing this. What's a good method for this kind of calculation?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep track of the current multiplier for each number in another table:

```
function calculateScore(a)
    local multipliers = {}
    local score = 0
    for i,number in ipairs(a) do
        local multiplier = multipliers[number] or 1
        multipliers[number] = multiplier + 1
        score = score + number * multiplier
    end
    return score
end

local a = {1,7,5,1,2,6,2,3,4,5,5,6,7,7,7}
local score = calculateScore(a)
```

Comment: And a slightly more compact version:function fsum(t)
  local x = { sum = 0 }
  for _,n in ipairs(t) do
    x[n] = (x[n] or 0) + 1
    x.sum = x.sum + x[n]*n
  end
  return x.sum
end